# Make canvas responsive only when resizing window and not when zooming

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a 960px width and 960px height html5 canvas game. I use Javascript to resize the canvas and rescale its content proportionally to always fit the window vertically (and horizontally too) so the bottom is never cut off since many screens are less than 960px high and some users don't even know they can zoom out with a desktop browser to fit the content. The code is:

```
var w = stage.canvas.width;
var h = stage.canvas.height;
var scaleFactor;

window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);

function resizeCanvas() {
    scaleFactor = Math.min(window.innerWidth / w, window.innerHeight / h);
    stage.canvas.width = scaleFactor * w;
    stage.canvas.height = scaleFactor * h;
    stage.scaleY = scaleFactor;
    stage.scaleX = scaleFactor;
}
```

My problem is the game also resizes itself when I zoom either in a desktop or in a mobile browser since zooming also changes `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` values. HOWEVER, I want the game to only resize itself when the window is resized but still be able to be zoomed (especially in small mobile screens) for people whose eyes are not so perfect.

I've been searching and trying different methods for weeks now, but I still haven't found any solutions. I would be very happy if someone could come up with a not-so-complicated solution since I'm relatively a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

When zooming in and out, the `devicePixelRatio` value does change.
So you can save this value at init and check if it has changed in the resize event to determine if the event was triggered by an actual resizing of the window, or by zooming.

```js
let dpr = window.devicePixelRatio;
onresize = e => {
  if(window.devicePixelRatio !== dpr){
    log.textContent = 'zoom event';
    dpr = window.devicePixelRatio
    }
  else{
    log.textContent = 'resize event';
    }
  };
```

```html
<pre id="log">Please see in full-page. 
Then, either zoom or resize the window</pre>
```

Or as a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1h1h17tj/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The window.devicePixelRatio does indeed change when I use ctrl +/- or zoom from the menu of a desktop browser, so it solved my problem on desktop devices. However, unfortunately it seems the value of window.devicePixelRatio remains unaffected on mobile browsers and on desktop version of Windows tablets when I pinch-zoom and it always remains the same. :(